# Which INDEX type should I use?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, indexing, average

I have a huge dataset (customer,timestamp,consumption).
I need to use an index to improve the performance of various queries, but I cannot seem to create any index that will boost up the performance of this specific query:

```
SELECT customer, AVG(consumption) 
FROM alicante_1y 
GROUP BY customer;
```

From what I have been reading, there is no easy/direct way to improve the performance of AVG function...

Any help appreciated. Thank you in advance.

explain (analyze, verbose) output:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=194302.67..194315.09 rows=993 width=16) (actual time=6847.581..6848.630 rows=994 loops=1)  
Output: customer, avg(consumption)
Group Key: alicante_1y.customer
->  Seq Scan on public.alicante_1y  (cost=0.00..150840.45 rows=8692445 width=16) (actual time=0.175..1829.867 rows=8692445 loops=1)
Output: customer, t, consumption
Planning time: 0.633 ms
Execution time: 6849.036 ms
```

Comment: As you are reading **all** rows from the table an index isn't going to help. An index helps if you need to reduce a lot of rows to a few rows based on some condition. To find out what makes your query slow you need to [edit] your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: just edited original post with the output.

Answer (score 0):

Your best best for an index is a covering index.  That would be:

```
create index idx_customer_consumption on alicante_1y(customer, consumption);
```

Postgres should also be able to use the index for the aggregation.

Comment: best best ? meaning , I think it would be best bet

Comment: I tried that already. Postgres does not use that index at all.

Comment: @OrestesPolyzos . . . That is really interesting.  It should at least use the index as a covering index for the query, saving on I/O.

Comment: I have ran to another similar issue with another query.
The same exact table makes use of an index I have set, when I run it from my laptop. However, it does not use it when I run it from my desktop.
Is there any known issue about this? Because if so, it maybe that 's the case? allthough neither my laptop nor my desktop makes use of the above index, we are talking about...

Comment: @GordonLinoff index-only scans [will be chosen only when](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans#Is_.22count.28.2A.29.22_much_faster_now.3F) *the index is significantly smaller than its table* (i.e. *the table's row width is much wider than some indexes'*). -- I only see a `t` column in the seq scan output, so I don't think that's the case.